# Return pretty json file in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using this setting for serializing file:

```
    public static string Serializer(this object obj)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        });
    }
```

and it returns this format:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Field\": \"Title\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROr\"\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

but I need to get something like this :

```
"[ 
   {"Field": "Title","Description": "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRROr" }
 ]"
```

i serlize by this way :

```
JToken.Parse(validationModelErrors.Serializer()).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, it looks like you are getting the proper result back.  \r\n is the C# representation of a Carriage Return (\r) and New Line (\n).  The \ before the " is the escape character for strings.  It looks as if you are basing this on the way it inspects.

If you use something like `File.WriteAllText()` with the results of your Serializer method it would be properly formatted.  The same would go with Console.WriteLine.

Comment: i usintg this `JToken.Parse(validationModelErrors.Serializer()).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)`

Comment: This appears to have it serialized to a string, to an object, and back to a string, is there a reason for this extra step?